# Inefficient memory storage for Dataset

Tags: performance-tuning, dataset, machine-learning, memory

Why `Dataset` doesn't serialize its contents, isn't it the whole point? I expect it to behave similar to python's `pandas.DataFrame`, R's `data.frame` and similar tabular data abstractions in other languages. Why on earth importing 100 Mb csv file with Wolfram results in 1 Gb `Dataset` expression in memory, which in turn results in terrible Data Science and Machine Learning experience for everyone. Is this issue being addressed somehow?

Comment: Minor remark, not related to the main issue in the question: I would say `Dataset` objects are more like R's [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), not so much as `data.frame`. Anyone willing to share an opinion on this?

Comment: @AntonAntonov You're right, in terms of usage their respective DSLs are indeed somewhat similar.

Comment: Thanks for confirming... :)

Comment: I think this is the kind of thing that should be forwarded to WRI support. It’s not bug per se but it does show a lack of performance WRI should be reminded of.

Comment: The Streaming project was supposed to address that. However, it's been stalled for some time, unfortunately. My development time is currently dedicated to a different project. But the more users request this functionality, the better are the chances that we will get needed dedicated time to bring this project to production.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I honestly rather have a release dedicated to performance enhancements and bug fixes than plethora of experimental features. It's nice and all to see all that interesting functionality coming up, as I like playing with new stuff, but it feels more and more bulky at an expense of smooth experience.

Comment: A really big problem with Dataset is that it does not have a formal query language, which would be restricted to operations which one could at least hope to implement efficiently. Right now, it is more like a nice formatting wrapper around hierarchical data, plus the rather nice `Query` machinery. But the main point is, it essentially allows one to use any Mathematica function on that data. And implementing out-of-core versions for  the entire variety of such operations is simply not feasible. It might be easier to define / implement a different data-frame-like object altogether.

Comment: @swish Does your CSV file contain header(s). Have you tried constructing this dataset without the header(s)? Also tangential does any one use external SQL database as a data store for WL?

Answer (score 9):

You may use [`ResourceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) [`TableSet`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TableSet/) from the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) for tabular data.

[`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) is optimized for hierarchical data with varying structure per row/node and has some overhead to manage that.

`TableSet` is for tabular data so has a much smaller footprint.

[image]

[image]

`TableSet` is also compatible with SQL-like functions such as [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html), [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), and others.

As the contributor of the function any feedback on its utility is welcome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that function posted recently. Waiting for an opportunity to use it :)